# Run code and return value in a Single-Threaded Apartment, where I can't set current apartment model

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a call that needs to be made in a single-apartment-thread context, but I can't guarantee that by setting `[STAThread]` in my code because I don't control the entrypoint, and my code will be called through reflection.

I've come up with this method of invoking the call and returning the token, but I'm hoping there's a better way:

```
private static string token;

private static Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope) // I don't control this signature, as it gets passed as a delegate
    {
        Thread t = new Thread(GetAuthToken);

        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        t.Join();

        return Task.Run(() =>
        {
            return token; 
        });
    }

    private static void GetAuthToken()
    {
        Credentials creds = AuthManagement.CreateCredentials(args); // this call must be STA
        token = creds.Token;
    }
```

My constraints:

- The first method's signature *must* be `Task<string> MyMethod(string, string, string)`
- `AuthManagement.CreateCredentials(args)` *must* be called in a single-threaded-apartment context
- The current thread context *cannot* be guaranteed to be STA, so should be assumed to be MTA.

I need to call that method in such a way that it's guaranteed to be STA, and return a result.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a slightly better way.  You will have to create a new thread to guarantee that you are on an STA thread since you can't change a thread's apartment state after it starts.  However you can get rid of the `Thread.Join()` call so that your method is actual asynchronous using [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
private static async Task<string> GetToken(string authority, string resource, string scope) // I don't control this signature, as it gets passed as a delegate
{
    using (var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>()) {
        Thread t = new Thread(() => GetAuthToken(tcs));
        t.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        t.Start();
        var token = await tcs.Task
        return token;
    }
}

private static void GetAuthToken(TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs)
{
    try {
       Credentials creds = AuthManagement.CreateCredentials(args); // this call must be STA
       tcs.SetResult(creds.Token);
    }
    catch(Exception ex) {
       tcs.SetException(ex);
    }
}
```

Also if you need to wrap a return value in a task, use `Task.FromResult()` instead of `Task.Run()`.

Comment: What's the difference between what I did (`Task.Run(() => {return n;})`) and `Task.FromResult()`?

Comment: Task.Run will run the return n statement on a thread pool and then complete the task.  Task.FromResult will immediately create a completed task object without running any extra code or running on a thread pool thread..